# vue.js redirection to another page(same code as original page) then database access 404 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a page that loads data in table from Mongodb database.

What I am trying to do is click a row of table then route to another page.

I did event handler to route another page when it clicked.

and set exactly same original page code with another vue file name.

on the original page, data loaded well but on another routed page, it shows an HTTP 404 error

program order is like this

```
User_Management.vue --(click table row)--> User_Management_detail.vue (url:/row.id)
└>PostService.js                           └>PostService.js 
  └> post_users.js                           └> post_users.js
```

both User_Management and _detail.vue page has same code.
but url is different(User_Management_detail/:id)

this is HTTP error

```
GET http://localhost:8080/User_Management_detail/api/posts_users/ 404 (Not Found)
```

<<router/index.js>>

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/User_Management",
    name: "User_Management",
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/User_Management.vue"),
  },
  {
    path: "/User_Management_detail/:id",
    name: "User_Management_detail",
    component: () =>
      import("../views/User_Management_copy.vue")
  },
];    

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
});
export default router;
```

<<User_Management/User_Management_detail.vue>>

```
 <template>
 <v-app
    :style="{ background: $vuetify.theme.themes.light.background }"
    style="max-height:100vw;"
  >
  <v-container style="width: 97%">
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title>
        Users
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-col class="text-right">
      <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="500px">
      <p class="error" v-if="error">{{ error }}</p>

      <v-data-table
        v-model="selected"
        :headers="headers"
        v-bind:index="posts.index"
        v-bind:item="posts.post"
        :items="posts"
        :single-expand="singleExpand"
        :expanded.sync="expanded"
        :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
        :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
        item-key="_id"
        show-select
        show-expand
        :search="search"
        class="[item.selected && 'selected']"
        @click:row="handleClick"
      > 
      </v-data-table>
    </v-card>
  </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import PostService from "../PostService";
export default {
  components: {},
  name: "PostComponent",
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
      error: "",
      text: "",
      sortBy: 'users_docs[0].createdAt',
      sortDesc: true,
      headers: [
        { text: "User G_ID", value: "_id" },
        { text: "User ID", value: "users_docs[0].userID" },
        { text: "First Name", value: "users_docs[0].firstName" },
        { text: "Last Name", value: "users_docs[0].lastName" },
        { text: "Department", value: "users_docs[0].department" },
        { text: "Role", value: "users_docs[0].role" },
        { text: "Status", value: "users_docs[0].status" },
        {
          text: "Enrollment Time",
          value: "users_docs[0].createdAt".toString()
        },
        { text: "Actions", value: "actions", sortable: false }
      ],      
      deviceName: ""
      }
    };
  },
  async created() {
    try {
      this.posts = await PostService.get_Users_Posts();
    } catch (err) {
      this.error = err.message;
    }
  },  
  methods: {
    handleClick(row) {
      console.log(row.users_docs[0]._id);
      alert(row.users_docs[0]._id)
      this.$router.push({path: `/User_Management_detail/:${row.users_docs[0]._id}`})
    }    
  }
};
</script>
```

<< postService.js >>

```
import axios from "axios";
const url_users = "api/posts_users/";
class PostService {
   // get users posts
   static get_Users_Posts() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(url_users);
        const data = res.data;
        resolve(
          data.map((post) => ({
            ...post,
                //createdAt: new Date(post.createdAt),
      }))
        );
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  }    
}
export default PostService;
```

<< post_users.js >>

```
const express = require('express');
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const router = express.Router();

// Get User Posts
router.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    const posts = await loadPostsCollection_Users();
    res.send(await posts.find({}).toArray());
});

async function loadPostsCollection_Users() {
    const client = await mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://ipAddr:port/tms', {
        useNewUrlParser: true
    });
    return client.db('tms').collection('integrated_users');
}
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: In your route when importing component, on both the places you are importing the same file i.e., User_Management.vue

Comment: @Hzk remove `windows.locaiton.ref` line, it not needed and use `$router.push` correctly this.$router.push({path: `/User_Management_detail/:${row.users_docs[0]._id}`})

Comment: What is this line in your code `this.$router.push({path: `/User_Management/:${row.users_docs[0]._id}`})`

Comment: @Nilesh Patel changed what you adviced thanks. but still not fixing issue :S

Comment: @Yash Maheshwari It's for redirecting to another page when I select(double click) data row on table

Comment: @HzK my bad try this 
this.$router.push({path: /User_Management_detail/`${row.users_docs[0]._id}`})

Comment: @Nilesh Patel, followed your advice but still 404 error when I get approach to DB in redirected page :'(

Comment: @HzK you must be doing something wrong. path should be ``/User_Management_detail/${row.users_docs[0]._id}`` enclosed by backtick. what you get in the browser url?

Comment: @Nilesh Patel After followed your comment above, I checked I can route to new page.
but it shows following error.  [Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)      api/posts_users/:1] and then cannot access to DB.

weird thing is, when I click that page from the menu and get in directly,
then it can access and fetch data from db.

but When i get in to that page by redirecting by this [/User_Management_detail/${row.users_docs[0]._id}] it's not working :S

Comment: here `id` is placeholder `api/posts_users/:id`. but actual url would be like `api/posts_users/1`, `api/posts_users/2`.. there should not be colon